# Navigation bar fill the parent div 100% with padding

Tags: css

Below is the code which produces the following navigation:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #b40404;
}
#wrapper {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 750px;
    padding-left: 1.5%;
    padding-right: 1.5%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #dc4b4b;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<ul>
  <li><a href="nav1.html">Nav 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="nav2.html">Nav 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="nav3.html">Nav 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I get the lighter red colour navigation completely fill the parent div with the extra 3% padding? The padding needs to be a percentage to allow the content to be responsive. I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so the question is : how can i keep the padding and remove the padding ?

Comment: The padding is needed for content further down the page but not for the navigation bar.

Comment: so remove it and keep it only for the content further down ... or use negative margin, but not the best way since you can control the padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the nav position absolute:

```css
body {
  background-color: #b40404;
}

#wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  max-width: 750px;
  padding-top:45px;
  padding-left: 1.5%;
  padding-right: 1.5%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position:relative;
}

ul {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  margin:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #dc4b4b;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.content {
  background:pink;
  padding:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="nav1.html">Nav 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="nav2.html">Nav 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="nav3.html">Nav 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="content">
    some content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any way of doing it without adding a separate div for the content? I've got this code on about 30 pages so not wanting to add a separate content div on each page.

Comment: @TCampbell no need a separte div, i simply added it to show the background and show that the padding is still there ... simply remove it and add the text directly